# Display table rows in angularjs, if data exists

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a table consisting of 3 columns, the code looks like this

```
    <table class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>

    <tr ng-if="$index%3==0" ng-repeat="permission in vm.parent.getAllPermissions(category)">
    <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">

    <span>

    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">                              {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i) || " "}}

</span> 
</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

That works great except for a small issue.

[image]

There's simply not enough json data to fill 3 rows, so 2 checkboxes are displayed empty

What I tried, is writing something like

```
vm.hasPermission = function(category, index) {
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);
    return permissions && index < permissions.length
};
```

And then something like

```
    <span>
    <input ng-if="vm.parent.hasPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)"type="checkbox"
 checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-
value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">                                                      {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i) || " "}}
    </span>
```

It fixes the problem but not on all tables, some tables would still have empty checkboxes.

I get the permission titles like this

```
vm.getPermissionTitle = function(category, index) {
    var permissions = vm.getAllPermissions(category);   
    if (index < permissions.length) {
     return i18n.get(permissions[index]);
    } else {
     return '';
    }
};
```

I tried removing the return, didn't fix it.

Comment: I would appreciate a fix without extra dependencies, like ng-tables.

Comment: would you please make live example ?

Comment: and check by replacing SPAN with DIV ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq ok thanks, I'll try that first, if didn't work then I'll try making a live example, the problem with that is I have to get json from somewhere, if I were to run in online

Comment: give me the live url of your app if you can ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq it's not online yet

Comment: when I need to "fake" json, I create an object with the json structure... handy for testing...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL will do that when I get home, unless you were able to fix the small remaining bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-if="$index%3==0" ng-repeat="permission in vm.parent.getAllPermissions(category)">
        <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
            <span ng-if="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">
                <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist- value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$parent.$index+i)">
    {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$parent.$index+i)}}
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So basically `{{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$parent.$index+i)}}`

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
<td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">                              {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i) || " "}}
    </span> 
</td>
```

for:

```
<td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
    <span ng-if="vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)!=''">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">                              {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)}}
    </span> 
</td>
```

if I understood well your code and your problem, `vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)` returns the text (permission) so just check that is not empty... it may also work like:

```
<td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
    <span ng-if="vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)">                              {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)}}
    </span> 
</td>
```

because `vm.parent.getPermission(category,$parent.$index+i)` returning nothing could evaluate false.

I haven't try it.

Comment: it did work but now everywhere, if there are only two rows to be displayed, it will display a third empty checkbox, but otherwise it's working, it's just there's a small bug remaining

Comment: then the bug is not in the code, but in the json, there must be a `vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)` returning a space or invisible characters...

Comment: actually your fix will make the data get repeated

Comment: Doing this: `<span ng-if="vm.parent.getPermissionTitle(category,$parent.$index+i)!=''">` cause the data to repeat? it should have something to do with the $index variable, but with the code you provided is hard to tell.